# Coloring alternating divs of certain class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="divs">
  <div class="row">row 0</div>
  <div class="not-row"></div>
  <div class="row">row 1</div>
  <div class="not-row"></div>
  <div class="row">row 2</div>
  <div class="not-row"></div>
  <div class="row">row 3</div> 
  <div class="not-row"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

This is supposed to paint the background of two of the rows gray and two of the rows white. Unfortunately it paints all of their backgrounds gray. What am I doing wrong?

I tried using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` but that didn't change anything.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b8ma1hon/1/)**

Comment: `nth-child` cannot be used this way. The first child under the parent is always `nth-child(1)` irrespective of whether it has the class or not. Class is only an additional criteria that must be satisfied. So for example, the second `div` with `class='row'` is actually the 3rd child and hence would be treated as `odd`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For even just use (as a default)

```
.row {}
```

Then override the odd ones with:

```
.row:nth-child(4n+1) {}
```

---

```
.row {
    background: #fff;
}
.row:nth-child(4n+1) {
   background: #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8ma1hon/3/

---

More on how `nth-child` works can be found here:

https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

[image]

---

You cannot simply use `even`/`odd` in this instance as that is in relation to all child elements, not just the ones with the class `row`.

Your inclusion of `.row` in the selector is purely an extra criteria and has no impact on the `nth-child` selector.

Likewise I could state:

```
.row:nth-child(1):hover {}
```

This would restrict selection to an element with a class of `row`, which is the 2nd child, which is currently in a hovered state.

It wouldn't make sense if this was the 2nd element out of all the hovered elements as you can only hover over one at a time.

I hope that makes sense!

---

It's also worth noting that your selector is now dependant on the `not-row` existing, or at least some kind of element existing between the `row` elements.

If this was to change then your selector would also have to change.

Alternatively you could change your element type for the `not-row` elements to something else so that you can make use of the `nth-of-type` selector:

```
<div class="divs">
    <div class="row">row 0</div>
    <span class="not-row"></span>
    <div class="row">row 1</div>
    <span class="not-row"></span>
    <div class="row">row 2</div>
    <span class="not-row"></span>
    <div class="row">row 3</div> 
    <span class="not-row"></span>
</div>

.row {
    background: #fff;
}
.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background: #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8ma1hon/5/

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. Can you comment on why what I tried doesn't work? Why do you need 4n+1 and not 2n+1?

Comment: @BenjyKessler Because you need every 4th item rather than every other item because you also have `not-row` as child elements. Remove them and you can use `2n+1`.

Comment: Why is it counting the not-rows? I specify .row. What does the .row mean if not choose the nth-child of type .row?

Comment: @BenjyKessler See my answer update with an example of `:hover`. Your inclusion of `.row` in the selector is just an extra criteria, it doesn't affect the `nth-child` selector.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the `4n+1` selector would work only if a `row` is always followed by `not-row`. If the order changes for whatever reason like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b8ma1hon/4/), the selector would still fail.

Comment: Hmm.. that seems dangerous. Is there any way to tell it to color every other row regardless of the other divs in the area?

Comment: @BenjyKessler: Nope, I don't think there is any way with pure CSS unless if you change the element type for `not-row` elements (in which case you can use `nth-of-type` selectors) or add extra classes to distinguish.

Comment: @Harry Answer updated :) Included suggestion to use `nth-of-type`.